# How long do food bonuses from Crab-N-Go last?

Tags: splatoon-3

If I buy food or drinks from Crab-N-Go to increase the XP or cash I get from battles, how long does the bonus effect last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bonus effects from Crab-N-Go last for 20 battles. This is shown in the top right when buying food.

[image: Remaining: 20]

You can see how many battles are left for your current food bonus on the matchmaking screen in the top-right status bar.

[image: matchmaking screen with bonus]

It can also be seen after a battle on the buttons that queue for a rematch.

[image: after battle bonus time remaining]